# Где можно найти обучающий материал по PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, python-3.7

Я учусь создавать программы с интерфейсом на PyQt5. И у меня возникла сложность в нахождении справочного материала. Подскажите где можно научится создавать программы на PyQt5. Какие нибудь видео уроки или сайты, где расскажут не только базовые знания. А уже по более профессиональные.

Comment: Ищите книги по Qt (4 и 5), хоть там будет по с++, но классы и логика работы с ними останется. Причем книг на русском на Qt хватает

Comment: насчет профессиональных сложно, а вот простых уроков туда сюда очень много, там и калькуляторы, и бд с sqlite и тд. Можно глянуть тут - http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/datetime/ , что то есть тут https://python-scripts.com/pyqt5#pyqt5-QDialog-QMainWindow-QWidget , это тоже может пригодиться https://evileg.com/ru/post/236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python 3 и PyQt 5. Разработка приложений](https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5369996) - толковая книга, много неочевидных фич, которые всегда упускаются в самоучителях на разных сайтах и построчное объяснение кода.

[PyScientist Notes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSyVru3RIxaHr4syFacyo7w) - канал на ютубе, тоже множество примеров PyQt5, в отличие от остальных - хорошо объясняет и тоже не совсем hello world примеры.

[Документация Qt на русском](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/). Единственное, что есть на русском. Правда, по четвертой версии, но по ходу дела можно несовместимые вещи решать уже как нарвёшься, их не так много.

Comment: По-моему, ваши предложения очень субъективны.

Comment: Не претендую. Однако из книг - это единственная, из всех, что я находил, которая удовлетворяет и актуальности(PyQt5) и объёмности(не только базовый уровень). На ютубе именно по пайтонQt материалов не так много, и большинство либо совсем начало, либо просто листинг одних и тех же программ.